# XML Deserialization from attributes to properties

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xml-serialization

How can I deserialize xml like this:

```
<query>
  <parameters>
    <param name="lastUpdate">2012-05-25</param>
    <param name="code">11222122</param>
    <param name="type">idnLookup</param>
  </parameters>
  <response>
    <category name="person" version="1">
      <field name="surname">Soap</field>
      <field name="name1">Joe</field>
      <field name="date_of_birth">1973-05-09</field>
    </category>
    <category name="contact" version="1">
      <row>
        <field name="phone">0118063433</field>
        <field name="type">home</field>
        <field name="date">2003-01-01</field>
      </row>
      <row>
        <field name="phone">0124666566</field>
        <field name="type">home</field>
        <field name="date">2008-03-11</field>
      </row>
   </category>
  </response>
</query>
```

into a class structure like this:

```
public class Query{
 public string lastUpdate {get;set;}
 public string code {get;set;}
 public string type {get;set;}
 public Response response {get;set;}
}
class Response{
  public Person person {get;set;}
  public Contact[] contacts {get;set;}
}
class Person {
  public string surname {get;set;}
  public string name1 {get;set;}
  public string date_of_birth {get;set;}
}
class Contact {
  public string phone {get;set;}
  public string type {get;set;}
  public string date {get;set;}
}
```

using the standard .net xml serializer.  Or do I need to roll my own?

Comment: The input is far too specific for the standard Xml serializer to be able to do this. I think you could run an XSL transform prior to a standard standard deserialization, but it may be easier to code custom c#... You can also have a look at the IXmlSerializable interface

Comment: @SimonMourier I would always advise a DTO model (a model between the domain model and the serialized form, that matches the serialization layer) before `IXmlSerializable` - that API is *horrendous* to get right. I do like the idea of XSLT here.

Comment: As a side note: whoever came up with that xml layout... doesn't know how to xml ;p

Comment: XML looks fine to me.  Nothing wrong with XML.  Need additional object for serialization.  The person want to do some additional parsing after serialization is done.  Nothing wrong with that.  Great idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand on Simon's xslt idea, consider the following xslt:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="/query/parameters">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
    <!-- removes a level from the hierarchy by applying directly -->
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="*[@name]">
    <xsl:element name="{@name}">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*[name()!='name'] | * | text()"/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The key match here is the `*[@name]`, which takes anything of the form:

```
<foo name="abc" ...>...</foo>
```

and rewrites it as:

```
<abc ...>...</abc>
```

This transforms your xml to:

```
<query>
  <lastUpdate>2012-05-25</lastUpdate>
  <code>11222122</code>
  <type>idnLookup</type>
  <response>
    <person version="1">
      <surname>Soap</surname>
      <name1>Joe</name1>
      <date_of_birth>1973-05-09</date_of_birth>
    </person>
    <contact version="1">
      <row>
        <phone>0118063433</phone>
        <type>home</type>
        <date>2003-01-01</date>
      </row>
      <row>
        <phone>0124666566</phone>
        <type>home</type>
        <date>2008-03-11</date>
      </row>
    </contact>
  </response>
</query>
```

Which can be mapped to your model with very minor tweaks as attributes:

```
[XmlRoot("query")] // <==== add this
public class Query {...}

[XmlArray("contact"), XmlArrayItem("row")] // <=== add this
public Contact[] contacts { get; set; }
```

Which can be used, for example:

```
static void Main()
{
    XslCompiledTransform xslt = new XslCompiledTransform();
    xslt.Load("my.xslt");
    var sw = new StringWriter();
    xslt.Transform("my.xml", null, sw);
    var transformedXml = sw.ToString();

    Console.WriteLine(transformedXml);
    Query query;
    using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(transformedXml)))
    {
        query = (Query)new XmlSerializer(typeof(Query)).Deserialize(reader);
    }
    // query is now fully populated
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Works like a charm.  and I +1'd Simon's comment for suggesting xslt

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication32
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\Test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Query));
            XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(FILENAME);
            Query query = (Query)xs.Deserialize(reader);
            query.Response.GetContacts();

        }
    }
    [XmlRoot("query")]
    public class Query
    {
        [XmlElement("parameters")]
        public Parameters Parameters {get;set;}
        [XmlElement("response")]
        public Response Response {get;set;}
    }
    [XmlRoot("parameters")]
    public class Parameters{
        private string lastUpdate {get;set;}
        private string code {get;set;}
        private string type {get;set;}

        [XmlElement("param")]
        public List<Param> m_params {get; set;}

    }
    [XmlRoot("param")]
    public class Param
    {
        [XmlAttribute("name")]
        public string name {get; set;} 
    }

    [XmlRoot("response")]
    public class Response
    {
      private Person person {get;set;}
      private List<Contact> contacts = new List<Contact>();
      [XmlElement("category")]
      public List<Category> categories {get;set;}

      public void GetContacts()
      {
          foreach (Category category in categories)
          {
              string catName = category.name;
              switch (catName)
              {
                  case "person" :
                      person = new Person();
                      foreach (Field field in category.fields)
                      {
                          switch (field.name)
                          {
                              case "surname" :
                                  person.surname = field.value;
                                  break;
                              case "name1":
                                  person.name1 = field.value;
                                  break;
                              case "date_of_birth":
                                  person.date_of_birth = field.value;
                                  break;
                              default :
                                  break;
                          }
                      }
                      break;
                  case "contact" :
                      foreach (Row row in category.row)
                      {
                          Contact newContact = new Contact();
                          contacts.Add(newContact);

                          foreach (Field field in row.fields)
                          {
                              switch (field.name)
                              {
                                  case "phone":
                                      newContact.phone = field.value;
                                      break;
                                  case "type":
                                      newContact.type = field.value;
                                      break;
                                  case "date":
                                      newContact.date = field.value;
                                      break;
                                  default:
                                      break;
                              }
                          }
                      }
                      break;
              }
          }
      }
    }
    [XmlRoot("category")]
    public class Category
    {
        [XmlAttribute("name")]
        public string name {get; set;}
        [XmlAttribute("version")]
        public string version { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("field")]
        public List<Field> fields {get; set;}
        [XmlElement("row")]
        public List<Row> row {get;set;}
    }
    [XmlRoot("row")]
    public class Row
    {
        [XmlElement("field")]
        public List<Field> fields {get; set;}
    }

    [XmlRoot("field")]
    public class Field
    {
        [XmlAttribute("name")]
        public string name { get; set; }
        [XmlText]
        public string value { get; set; }
    }

    class Person {
      public string surname {get;set;}
      public string name1 {get;set;}
      public string date_of_birth {get;set;}
    }
    class Contact {
      public string phone {get;set;}
      public string type {get;set;}
      public string date {get;set;}
    }
}
```